# simple gallery next prev button background images

Tags: jquery, button, background, gallery

I am trying to create a very simple gallery with background images on the body tag and previous /next buttons.
Therefor I created an array containing the images and calling the actual index. Unfotrunately I can not call the first image bg_01.Jpg to start with and my prev/next buttons stop at the third image?
I also created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MiauMiau/81trLyt2/130/): 
Any help would be appreciated.

```html
var Images = ['bg_01, bg_02', 'bg_03', 'bg_04', 'bg_05', 'bg_06', 'bg_07', 'bg_08', 'bg_09', 'bg_10', 'bg_11', 'bg_12'];
var ImgLength = Images.length;
$("body").css("background-image", "url(../img/" + Images[0] + ".jpg)");
$('#panel .left').click(function () {
    if (ImgLength > 0) {
        ImgLength = ImgLength - 1;
    } else {
        ImgLength = 0;
    }
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(../img/" + Images[ImgLength] + ".jpg)");
    return false;
});

$('#panel .right').click(function () {
    if (ImgLength < Images.length - 1) {
        ImgLength = ImgLength + 1;
    } else {
        ImgLength = 0;
    }
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(../img/" + Images[ImgLength] + ".jpg)");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array has a mistake:

```
['bg_01, bg_02',...
```

you've missed to close `'bg_01'` and open `'bg_02'` strings

so your array's first element is `'bg_01, bg_02'`